# docker build eating up over 30 gigs of space in /var/lib/docker/tmp and /var/lib/docker/overlay2 with rust project

Tags: docker, rust, target, arch

I am on Archlinux and am executing a simple docker build for a rust project that has a `target` directory of 12GB.

Due to this problem, I have moved the `/var/lib/docker` directory to `/data/arch/var/lib/docker` with: `rsync -avg /var/lib/docker /data/arch/var/lib/` and `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and `ln -s /data/arch/var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker`

The problem still persisted as the build reaches over 30GB which is all the free space I have on the data partition.

Inside the `/data/arch/var/lib/docker` directory, the `tmp` directory will grow to 12GB. Then the `overlay2` will have at least 2 sub-directories grow with each having a `diff` directory and a `merged` directory both containing an `app/target` that will contain 12GB.

```
/data/arch/var/lib/docker
  /tmp -> 12GB
  /overlay2
    /dirXXX1
      /merged/app/target -> 12GB
      /diff/app/target -> 12GB
    /dirXXX2
      /merged/app/target -> 12GB
      /diff/app/target -> 12GB
```

However, the dirXXX2 directory doesn't actually get to 24GB as the build will run out of space and kill the whole process.

This seems overly excessive to me and wondering if something can be reconfigured here.

UPDATE:

I have also added to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{ 
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
  "log-driver": "local",
  "log-opts": {
      "max-size": "100m",
      "max-file": "3"
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.72.0

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && apt install lld clang -y

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release

ENTRYPOINT ["./target/release/zero2prod"]
```

Comment: What does your dockerfile look like? Do you have any wasted space in your layers?

Comment: @ESG Updated with Dockerfile

Comment: Not sure what you mean by layers.

Comment: a "simplified" explanation is that (almost) every line in a docker file creates a new layer.

Comment: @ESG, thank tyou for the explanation. I feel like the Dockerfile is pretty simple. I think what I will do in a bit is create another data partition and move my timeshift directory to that partition to free up another 40 GB. Hopefully that will do the trick and hopefully some of that space in question is reclaimed once the build is complete.

Comment: Do you have a `target` subdirectory in the source directory already? If so, then add `target` to a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file. Otherwise, the `COPY . .` command is copying the `target` from the host to the container build environment.

Comment: @FrancisGagné I will try this next. I am actually packaging the target with the docker build. I do believe I should ignore that.

Comment: @FrancisGagné, this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `target` directory to a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file in your project, otherwise:

1. the whole `target` directory from the host (if present) needs to be sent to the Docker daemon, which takes a while when it's several gigabytes big; and
2. the `COPY . .` command in your `Dockerfile` copies the `target` directory from the host into the layer for that command.

(In general, you probably want to keep your `.dockerignore` in sync with your `.gitignore`/`.hgignore`/etc., but for Rust projects, the `target` directory is especially important.)

Answer (score 1):

Your current docker image includes not only the final build, but all source files leading to that, which are not required in the image

I'd consider using multi-stage builds to keep your image size smaller

For example, you could do something like:

```
FROM rust:1.72.0 as builder
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt update && apt install lld clang -y
COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update & apt-get install -y extra-runtime-dependencies & rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/zero2prod /usr/local/bin/zero2prod
CMD ["zero2prod"]
```

(note: I haven't tested this, but it should give you a general idea)

Reference: https://www.docker.com/blog/simplify-your-deployments-using-the-rust-official-image/

Comment: The issue was that I was not ignoring the target directory. However, this answer introduced some helpful material.